# spring xml file not found

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have seen this question here before, but haven't been able to figure out the issue. I am using spring in my Java project and the xml file, although it exists, cannot be found.

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from URL     [file:/cs373p1Facilitiesold/resources/FaciltiesContext.xml]
Exception in thread "main"     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException     parsing XML document from URL     [file:/cs373p1Facilitiesold/resources/FaciltiesContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: \cs373p1Facilitiesold\resources\FaciltiesContext.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at main.view.FacilityMain.main(FacilityMain.java:22)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:     \cs373p1Facilitiesold\resources\FaciltiesContext.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

this is my .classpath

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="resources"/>
```

this is the code where I am instantiating the application context

```
ApplicationContext factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:/cs373p1Facilitiesold/resources/FaciltiesContext.xml");
```

[image: This is a screenshot of my project setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using **ClassPath**XmlApplicationContext, no need to use file:// or /resources/ in your path.

Below code will work.

```
ApplicationContext factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("FaciltiesContext.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

When the project is being compiled, everything from `java` and `resource` folder goes to root directory. So no need to specify complete location.

Just put the file name and it should work.

```
ApplicationContext factory = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("FaciltiesContext.xml");
```